# Android: String from SQLite can not be set as HTML in Textview

Tags: java, android, html, sqlite, textview

Hi I have an response from backend API with HTML string format, and I put into textview as HTML in android using:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
     sinopsis.setText(Html.fromHtml(summaryText, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));
}else{
     sinopsis.setText(Html.fromHtml(summaryText));
}
```

**The problem is:**

If I put response from API direct into Textview the result is correct show as HTML parsed like `<br/>, &nbsp;` tags not shown as html code

```
Hi this is example from API response
Thanks
```

but if I save the result into SQLite as string and get in to Textview shown as pure html code

```
Hi this is example from API response <br />Thanks
```

[image]
I no idea to solve this case, anyone can help me please.

Comment: solved: I use replace function for string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved: I translated some html into string function in Android like 
 into \n